# Parsing a raw string int a golang struct in go gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I have data coming from a request in text/plain in this format:

```
machine_id=XXX&v_k=44&v_dr=4.0&v_total=44.9&message="Idle Data"
```

How can I parse this into a struct or a `map[string]string` in golang?

```
type Event struct {
    MachineID    string  `json:"machine_id"`
    Message      string  `json:"message"`
    VDr         float64 `json:"v_dr"`
    VKeg         float64 `json:"v_k"`
    VTotal       float64 `json:"v_total"`
}
```

I am looking to the equivalent of

```
jsonMap := make(map[string]interface{})
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &jsonMap)
```

or

```
var p Event
err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&p)
```

if the raw string was json formatted. I cannot change the Header coming from the client to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and handle this as a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ParseQuery` method in the `url` package will do it, with the caveat that the item you have in quotes, message="Idle Data", might not parse quite right, meaning you'll want to call `url.PathEscape` first.

`url.ParseQuery("machine_id=XXX&v_k=44&v_dr=4.0&v_total=44.9&message=Idle+Data"))`

[ParseQuery](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseQuery) returns a `Values` type, which is just `map[string][]string`

If this is coming from an HTTP request, though. the Request object has a method to handle parsing the query string. It's [Parse Form](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm)

https://play.golang.org/p/NUvrXnsPM89